# How F# returns booleans from AND operation?

Tags: f#

I am rather new to F# and just curious about the complexity of my solution to a task. I am not going to explain the whole task I am solving, but the idea is that I would like to return a boolean based on whether all elements of some list satisfy some filter. I am going through the list recursively and checking whether the element satisfies the filter or not and then just return the result AND the next result I get from calling the same function on tail.

When doing so, I got curious whether I should check for false on each step, as the result of AND operation is false as soon as any member of the operation is false. Or does F# return false as soon as it gets false from some element in AND operation itself?

Example:

```
// I have a function check : int -> bool
// check 1 returns false
check 1 && check 2
```

Does `check 2` get executed or is the value returned instantly after `check 1`, as it returns false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` short circuits. If `check 1` returns `false`, then `check 2` is never executed.

You can see this in action if you allow `check x` to have a side effect:

```
let check n =
    printfn "Checking %i" n
    n = 1

check 2 && check 1 // Just prints 'Checking 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if all members in a list satisfy a predicate, there exists already the built in function `List.forall`.

**Example**

`List.forall (fun x -> x < 10) [1..10] //false`

Comment: It might be worth adding that this function also short circuits.